# Is there any way to log all the methods in one assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, logging, frameworks

I would like to know if I would be able to add a Console.WriteLine each time a method or setter is called.

For example:

```cs
public void Test() => _do.Something();
```

whenever that method is called add a

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Method [name] was called");
```

at the end, and possibly the name of the assembly who called the method.

In each method a file has so I don't have to add that manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this idea is that it may have an incredible performance penalty. In many cases the logging may take much longer than the actual work the method does.

It is however possible. Some profiling tools have modes that does similar things to this. From [Dot trace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/Profiling_Guidelines__Choosing_the_Right_Profiling_Mode.html#tracing) tracing mode.

> Unlike sampling, tracing revolves around a function, or more precisely, around function entry and exit.
> dotTrace receives notifications from CLR when a function is entered and then when it is left, even if it is left because of an exception. The time between these two notifications is considered as the execution time of the function.

But this uses a highly optimized form of logging, but even then the performance penalty is significant. So this is something usually only done when there is a performance problem that needs investigating, and the other profiling modes are insufficient.

If you want to debug issues rather than performance you should familiarize yourself with the [debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022). The debugging tools is the main way to find problems, and is much more flexible and useful than "printf debugging" that is fairly common for new programmers.

It is also fairly common to insert checks to validate assumptions about the software. Either as `Debug.Assert` to only run the check in debug-mode, or log and/or throw an exception if the assumption is violated.